# Unable to install cassandra in mac

Tags: macos, cassandra, homebrew, cassandra-2.0

Because of no of versions available of cassandra on my mac sytem and unable to find cassandra.yaml file in system.I uninstalled all of them.And also removed these files because I am not sure about these files why they are present here

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/cassandra@3.10
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/cassandra.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/cassandra@2.1.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/cassandra@2.2.rb
```

Now again trying command

```
brew install cassandra@2.1 
gives error
Error: No available formula with the name "cassandra@2.1" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
cassandra@2.1 was deleted from homebrew/core in commit 18cdc6b:
  cassandra@2.1: add 2.1.13 bottle.

To show the formula before removal run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" show 18cdc6b^:Formula/cassandra@2.1.rb

If you still use this formula consider creating your own tap:
  http://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.html
```

and command

```
brew search cassandra
gives error
cassandra was deleted from homebrew/core in commit d20fe73:
  cassandra: update 3.10_1 bottle.

To show the formula before removal run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" show d20fe73^:Formula/cassandra.rb

If you still use this formula consider creating your own tap:
  http://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.html
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @l'L'l brew install cassandra not working.In question I already mentioned the errors.

Comment: The errors state that it's not installed though... so for all intensive purposes it's uninstalled.

Comment: @l'L'l  I removed some files form folder  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/  which I mentioned above . I think thats why I am getting error because it works on git(Homebrew) and I already removed cassandra related .rb files from that folder.Thats why It gives error during installation using command "brew install cassandra" or "brew install cassandra@2.1" because it can't find cassandra.rb and cassandra@2.1.rb file in folder /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/  which I already deleted.But I don't know to get things back.

Comment: It says "cassandra@2.1 was deleted from homebrew/core in commit 18cdc6b", and below that it states "cassandra@2.1: add 2.1.13 bottle", so maybe you need to use `brew install cassandra@2.1.13`? I don't use Homebrew, so that's just speculation; probably wouldn't hurt to try it though.

Comment: @ l'L'l   brew install cassandra@2.1.13 gives Error: No available formula with the name "cassandra@2.1.13" which is obvious because cassandra@2.1.rb got deleted.

Comment: Based off that then I would assume you would just use `brew install cassandra`...

Comment: @l'L'l I already mentioned it is not working . I find only solution "brew upgrade" maybe it will save my life.I will give update if everything will work fine.If you have any other solution it will be most welcomed.

Comment: I was under the impression you were specifically trying `brew install cassandra@2.1`, so my mistake if you've mentioned that already. I really don't have any more suggestions other than maybe consider ditching homebrew and go with MacPorts.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for being part of discussion.After brew upgrade stills things not working these cassandra.rb ,cassandra@2.1.rb and cassandra@2.2.rb   are still missing .Hoping for somebody gives any solution else I have to ask another question what will we should do if somebody removed .rb file or played with brew folders.

Comment: Why don't yo simply download the deleted files from the [Homebrew-core GIT](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula)?

Comment: @SB87 Downloading from git worked thanks  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43235245/6497665) was same as you explained.